# Aggregation and how to check if we can sum objects

Tags: c#, .net, interface, aggregation

I need to write something I call Aggregation Container, which stores Aggregations, which are essentially Actions that take a collection of objects and output a single object as a result. Examples of Aggregations would be: Arithmetic Mean, Median of a set of numbers, Harmonic Mean etc. Here's a sample code.

```
var arithmeticMean = new Aggregation
        {
            Descriptor = new AggregationDescriptor { Name = "Arithmetic Mean" },
            Action = (IEnumerable arg) =>
            {
                double count = 0;
                double sum = 0;

                foreach (var item in arg)
                {
                    sum += (double)item;
                    count++;
                }

                return sum / count;
            }
        };
```

Here's my problem with the code. I have assumed that the objects were just double and hence made a conversion. What if they're not double? How can I make sure that I'm allowed to sum two objects? Is there some kind of interface for that in standard .Net assemblies? I need something like ISummable... Or do I need to implement it myself (then I will have to wrap all primitive types like double, int, etcetera to support it).

Any advice regarding the design of such functionality will be helpful.

Comment: The problem is not that you need to determine if a collection is "summable". All numeric values are inherently summable. The question you should be asking instead is "Is `arg` a collection of numbers?". You can try either providing strongly typed variations of `Action` for different numeric types, or runtime casts on `arg`.

Comment: Jon, thank's for the reply. I know, the examples I have given are all numeric... But I would really like to write something more generic and useful. I wouldn't like to write a bunch of runtime casts there but I suggest a set of Actions with different types of arguments would work here...

Comment: Take a look on Enumerable methods - it has set of generic methods parametrized with each type it supports: `Sum<int>, Sum<double>, Sum<decimal>, Sum<Nullable<int>>` etc. That's the only way to make type parameter to be 'summable'

Comment: It depends on your goals. If you assume that `arg` must contains only numbers - try to cast your arg to IEnumerable<double>. In case when there appears non-numeric values you should throw ArgumentException.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky +1, although I think the real problem here is not so much how to sum but what the signature of `Action` would be to support propagating the type.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I guess that's the only way to do it. Please, add it as an answer, I will accept it, if no one proposes something better in a couple of hours.

Comment: @george.zakaryan sure, I'll add it

Comment: Seems to me like you would just test to see if `item` was a numeric type and if not throw an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on `Enumerable` class methods - it has set of methods parametrized with each type it supports:

```
int Sum(this IEnumerable<int> source)
double Sum(this IEnumerable<double> source)
decimal Sum(this IEnumerable<decimal> source)
long Sum(this IEnumerable<long> source)
int? Sum(this IEnumerable<int?> source)
// etc
```

That's the only way to make method argument to be 'summable'.

Unfortunately you can't create some generic method with generic [type parameter constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), which will allow only types with +operator overloaded. There is no constraint for operators in .NET, also operators cannot be part of some interface (thus they are static). So, you can't use operators with variables of generic type.

Also if you will look on .NET primitive types definitions, you will not find any interface which can help you here - only comparing, formatting, and converting are implemented:

```
public struct Int32 : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, 
                      IComparable<int>, IEquatable<int>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `Action` property in the class like:

```
public Func<IEnumerable<double>, double> Action { get; set; }
```

So it would only except `IEnumerable<double>` and returns a `double` result.

Comment: I'm actually trying to abstract away from the type of the collection, so that I can sum anything that can be summed somehow.

Comment: @george.zakaryan Then you can create 2 overloads for Action: `Action(IEnumerable<double>)` and `Action(IEnumerable<ISummable>)` where ISummable should be your interface. Double implicitly casts to any other numeric type.